# DO I need to create a custom authentication provider for facebook connect + spring security in grails?

Tags: grails, facebook, spring-security

Do I need to write a custom authentication provider to use facebook connect with account registration + authorization for the Spring Security plugin in Grails?  I am trying to offer the traditional application registration with facebook connect in a grails dev app using Spring Security.   Does this make sense?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can inspiration in [spring-security-facebook](http://code.google.com/p/spring-security-facebook/) project. But the project is no longer has an active development.

Other possibility is to use [Apache Shiro plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/shiro) which has facebook login or [nimble plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/nimble).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts... I am currently toying around with the Shiro plugin + Facebook Graph plugin.  I tried Nimble, I wanted to have a bit more control and figured it would be in my best interest to learn a bit more about Shiro in general.